# How to remove all directories and files while uninstalling python module

Tags: python, uninstallation, setup.py

Apart from library files my python module is installing examples directory also.
When I am updating mu modules, my example folder is not getting updated.
I am updating using

```
   sudo pip install -U git+https://github.com/jainpriyal/abc.git
```

When I am trying to uninstall it and then install new version, it is not removing my example folder:

```
(venv)sh-3.2# pip uninstall abc
Uninstalling abc-0.1:
/Users/jpriyal/Desktop/developement/systest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/abc/samples/test_all_same.yml
/Users/jpriyal/Desktop/developement/systest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/abc/samples/test_all_same2.yml
........
....
/Users/jpriyal/Desktop/developement/systest/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/abc-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? y
Not removing or modifying (outside of prefix):
/etc/jsnapy/samples/__init__.py
/var/log/abc/abc.log
/etc/jsnapy/samples/test1.yml
/etc/jsnapy/samples/test2.yml
/etc/jsnapy/samples/test3.yml
Successfully uninstalled abc-0.1
```

How to remove/update examples folder??

Comment: hey, did you ever figured this out?